# Find and replace text within a file using commands

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I find and replace specific words in a text file using command line?

Answer (score 1488, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `sed` = Stream EDitor
- `-i` = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file)
- The command string:

  - `s` = the substitute command
  - `original` = a regular expression describing the word to replace (or just the word itself)
  - `new` = the text to replace it with
  - `g` = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)
- `file.txt` = the file name

Comment: How do you incorporate regex with this?

Comment: @Akiva If you include [regex special characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions) in your search `sed` will match them. Add a `-r` flag if you want to use extended REs instead.

Comment: Can I use the "sed -i" command when the strings "original" and "new" contain special characters like "/" or similar?

Comment: @mcExchange If it's specifically the `/` character that you need to match, you can just use some other character as the separator (e.g. `'s_old/text_new/text_g'`).  Otherwise, you can put a `\ ` before any of `$ * . [ \ ^` to get the literal character.

Comment: I just tried this on a Unix (non-Linux) system and it somehow deleted the  permissions on the file!?!

Comment: @BrianZ As far as the file system is concerned the output of sed is a new file with the same name. It's one of the [commonly reported bugs that are not bugs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Reporting-Bugs)

Comment: You may want `s/\boriginal\b/new/g` instead of `s/original/new/g` (`\b` matches at a word boundary) to only replace whole words.

Comment: The OSX command `sed -i '.bak' 's/original/new/g' file.txt` can also be run with a zero-length extension `sed -i '' 's/original/new/g' file.txt`, which will generate no backup.

Comment: MacOS users will have to add ''" after -i as a parameter for -i https://ed.gs/2016/01/26/os-x-sed-invalid-command-code/ so that the file will be overwritten.

Comment: @cscarney I want to replace all `original` with `new` except `original.txt`. How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure if this used to be correct, but I just tried this on the Mac and had to add `-e` before the regexp/replace statement (e.g. `sed -i -e 's/orig/new/g' file.txt`

Comment: **if your regex is failing, try with** `-r` **aka** `--regexp-extended` **flag**.  My simple pattern was failing without this.  From the manual pages: *"POSIX.2  BREs  should  be supported, but they aren't completely because of performance problems.  The \n sequence in a regular expression matches the newline character, and similarly for \a, \t, and other sequences."*

Comment: What if it's multiline to multiline??

Comment: Anyway to disable the `RegEx` mode and have them as strings only?

Comment: What if I have to replace all occurrences in all files of any extension in the current dir?

Comment: @Maseed you can use a glob (e.g. `*`, `*.txt`) in place of a file name

Comment: is it possible to replace the text but the text I am going to replace it with is coming from another file

Comment: @NeonWarge https://askubuntu.com/questions/540532/replacing-a-string-by-a-file-using-sed

Comment: In case you are trying to replace paths containing the `/` char, you must use a different char in the `sed` command. It allows any char to be used there I believe, so I recommend `|`, like this: `sed -i 's|original|new|g' file.txt`

Answer (score 73):

There's multitude of ways to achieve it. Depending on the complexity of what one tries to achieve with string replacement, and depending on tools with which user is familiar, some methods may be preferred more  than others.

In this answer I am using simple `input.txt` file, which you can use to test all examples provided here. The file contents:

```
roses are red , violets are blue
This is an input.txt and this doesn't rhyme
```

#### BASH

Bash isn't really meant for text processing, but simple substitutions can be done via [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) , in particular here we can use simple structure `${parameter/old_string/new_string}`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
       *blue*) printf "%s\n" "${line/blue/azure}" ;;
       *) printf "%s\n" "$line" ;;
    esac
done < input.txt
```

This small script doesn't do in-place replacement, meaning that you would have to save new text to new file, and get rid of the old file, or `mv new.txt old.txt`

Side note: if you're curious about why `while IFS= read -r ; do ... done < input.txt` is used, it's basically shell's way of reading file line by line. See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for reference.

#### AWK

AWK, being a text processing utility, is quite appropriate for such task. It can do simple replacements and much more advanced ones based on [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). It provides two functions: `sub()` and `gsub()`. The first one only replaces only the first occurrence, while the second - replaces occurrences in whole string. For instance, if we have string `one potato two potato` , this would be the result:

```
$ echo "one potato two potato" | awk '{gsub(/potato/,"banana")}1'
one banana two banana

$ echo "one potato two potato" | awk '{sub(/potato/,"banana")}1'                                      
one banana two potato
```

AWK can take an input file as argument, so doing same things with `input.txt` , would be easy:

```
awk '{sub(/blue/,"azure")}1' input.txt
```

Depending on the version of AWK you have, it may or may not have in-place editing, hence the usual practice is save and replace new text. For instance something like this:

```
awk '{sub(/blue/,"azure")}1' input.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt input.txt
```

#### SED

Sed is a line editor. It also uses regular expressions, but for simple substitutions it's sufficient to do:

```
sed 's/blue/azure/' input.txt
```

What's good about this tool is that it has in-place editing, which you can enable with `-i` flag.

#### Perl

Perl is another tool which is often used for text processing, but it's a general purpose language, and is used in networking, system administration, desktop apps, and many other places. It borrowed a lot of concepts/features from other languages such as C,sed,awk, and others. Simple substitution can be done as so:

```
perl -pe 's/blue/azure/' input.txt
```

Like sed, perl also has the -i flag.

#### Python

This language is very versatile and is also used in  a wide variety of applications. It has a lot of functions for working with strings, among which is `replace()`, so if you have variable like `var="Hello World"` , you could do `var.replace("Hello","Good Morning")`

Simple way to read file and replace string in it would be as so:

```
python -c "import sys;lines=sys.stdin.read();print lines.replace('blue','azure')" < input.txt
```

With Python, however, you also need to output to new file , which you can also do from within the script itself. For instance, here's a simple one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import tempfile

tmp=tempfile.mkstemp()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd1, open(tmp[1],'w') as fd2:
    for line in fd1:
        line = line.replace('blue','azure')
        fd2.write(line)

os.rename(tmp[1],sys.argv[1])
```

This script is to be called with `input.txt` as command-line argument. The exact command to run python script with command-line argument would be

```
 $ ./myscript.py input.txt
```

or

```
$ python ./myscript.py input.txt
```

Of course, make sure that `./myscript.py` is in your current working directory and for the first way, ensure it is set executable with `chmod +x ./myscript.py`

Python can also have regular expressions , in particular, there's `re` module, which has `re.sub()` function, which can be used for more advanced replacements.

Comment: Nice compilation! Another possible way not mentioned here is using the `tr` command in unix

Comment: @TapajitDey  Yes, `tr`  is another great tool, but note that it is for replacing sets of characters ( for example `tr  abc cde` would translate `a` to `c` , `b` to `d`. It is a bit different from replacing whole words as with `sed` or `python`

Answer (score 38):

There are a number of different ways to do this. One is using `sed` and Regex. SED is a Stream Editor for filtering and transforming text. One example is as follows:

```
marco@imacs-suck: ~$ echo "The slow brown unicorn jumped over the hyper sleeping dog" > orly
marco@imacs-suck: ~$ sed s/slow/quick/ < orly > yarly
marco@imacs-suck: ~$ cat yarly
The quick brown unicorn jumped over the hyper sleeping dog
```

Another way which may make more sense than `< strin` and `> strout` is with pipes!

```
marco@imacs-suck: ~$ cat yarly | sed s/unicorn/fox/ | sed s/hyper/lazy/ > nowai
marco@imacs-suck: ~$ cat nowai 
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy sleeping dog
```

Comment: note the `cat` in `cat file | sed '...'` is unnecessary. You can directly say `sed '...' file`.

Comment: Indeed this can be reduced further: `sed -i'.bak' -e 's/unicorn/fox/g;s/hyper/brown/g' yarly` will take file yarly and do the 2 changes in-place whilst making a backup. Using `time bash -c "$COMMAND"` to time it suggests that this version is a ~5 times faster.

Answer (score 27):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -s -c '%s/OLD/NEW/g|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `g` replace all instances in each line
4. `x` write if changes have been made (they have) and exit

Answer (score 23):

Through awk's gsub command,

```
awk '{gsub(/pattern/,"replacement")}' file
```

**Example:**

```
awk '{gsub(/1/,"0");}' file
```

In the above example, all the 1's are replaced by 0's irrespective of the column where it located.

---

If you want to do a replacement on a specific column, then do like this,

```
awk '{gsub(/pattern/,"replacement",column_number)}' file
```

**Example:**

```
awk '{gsub(/1/,"0",$1);}' file
```

It replaces 1 with 0 on the first column only.

Through Perl,

```
$ echo 'foo' | perl -pe 's/foo/bar/g'
bar
```

Answer (score 14):

`sed` is the [**s**tream **ed**itor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt), in that you can use `|` (pipe) to send *standard streams* (STDIN and STDOUT specifically) through `sed` and alter them programmatically on the fly, making it a handy tool in the Unix philosophy tradition; but can edit files directly, too, using the `-i` parameter mentioned below.
**Consider the following**:

```sh
sed -i -e 's/few/asd/g' hello.txt
```

`s/` is used to **s**ubstitute the found expression `few` with `asd`:

> The few, the brave.
>
> ---
>
> The asd, the brave.

`/g` stands for "global", meaning to do this for the whole line. If you leave off the `/g` (with `s/few/asd/`, there always needs to be three slashes no matter what) and `few` appears twice on the same line, only the first `few` is changed to `asd`:

> The few men, the few women, the brave.
>
> ---
>
> The asd men, the few women, the brave.

This is useful in some circumstances, like altering special characters at the beginnings of lines (for instance, replacing the greater-than symbols some people use to quote previous material in email threads with a horizontal tab while leaving a quoted algebraic inequality later in the line untouched), but in your example where you specify that *anywhere* `few` occurs it should be replaced, make sure you have that `/g`.

The following two options (flags) are combined into one, `-ie`:

`-i` option is used to edit **i**n place on the file `hello.txt`.

`-e` option indicates the **e**xpression/command to run, in this case `s/`.

Note: It's important that you use `-i -e` to search/replace. If you do `-ie`, you create a backup of every file with the letter 'e' appended.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
locate <part of filaname to locate> | xargs sed -i -e "s/<Old text>/<new text>/g"
```

Examples:
to replace all occurrences [logdir', ''] (without [] ) with [logdir', os.getcwd()] in all files that are result of locate command, do:

ex1:

```
locate tensorboard/program.py | xargs sed -i -e "s/old_text/NewText/g"
```

ex2:

```
locate tensorboard/program.py | xargs sed -i -e "s/logdir', ''/logdir', os.getcwd()/g"
```

where [tensorboard/program.py] is file to search

Comment: Hi.  Your choice of strings (`logdir', ''` -> `/logdir', os.getcwd()`) makes this answer hard to parse.  Also, it's worth specifying that your answer first locates the files to use sed on, because it's not part of the question.

Comment: Hi, this answer is both search and replace all if it found <old text> in the file.

Comment: I choose this answer for all they use tensorboard in keras, who want to change command from:
tensorboard --logdir='/path/to/log/folder/'
to use:
tensorboard
only, when staying in logs folder. it is very convenient

Answer (score 1):

### Finding and replacing across *many* files

In order to achieve as close to lightning speed or warp velocity as possible when doing find and replace *across multiple files* (maybe even thousands or millions) in massive filesystems such as huge code repos, I recommend using Ripgrep (`rg`) which is awesome and incredibly fast. Unfortunately, it doesn't support find and replace in files, and according to the author [probably never will](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74#issuecomment-249421612) (update: [*definitely* never will](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74#issuecomment-1191336022)), so we have to use some work-arounds.

### Ripgrep-based Method 1 (the easy, but more-limited 1-liner)

Here is the first work-around: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74#issuecomment-376659557

Use Ripgrep (`rg`) to find files containing the matches, then pipe a list of those files to `sed` to do the text replacement in those files:

```bash
# Replace `foo` with `bar` in all matching files in the current
# directory and down
rg 'foo' --files-with-matches | xargs sed -i 's|foo|bar|g'
```

### Ripgrep-based Method 2 (my recommended choice)

Here is the 2nd work-around: [use my `rgr` (Ripgrep Replace) wrapper script](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/ripgrep_replace) I have written around Ripgrep which adds the `-R` option to replace contents on your disk. Installation is simple. Just follow the instructions at the top of that file. Usage is super simple too:

```bash
# Replace `foo` with `bar` in all matching files in the current
# directory and down
rgr 'foo' -R bar
```

Since it's a wrapper around `rg`, it also provides access to all of Ripgrep's other options and features. Here is the full help menu at this moment, with more usage examples:

```bash
rgr ('rgr') version 0.1.0

RipGrep Replace (rgr). This program is a wrapper around RipGrep ('rg') in order to allow some
extra features, such as find and replace in-place in files. It doesn't rely on 'sed'. It uses
RipGrep only. Since it's a wrapper around 'rg', it forwards all options to 'rg', so you can use it
as a permanent replacement for 'rg' if you like.

Currently, the only significant new option added is '-R' or '--Replace', which is the same as
RipGrep's '-r' except it MODIFIES THE FILES IN-PLACE ON YOUR FILESYSTEM! This is great! If you
think so too, go and star this project (link below).

USAGE (exact same as 'rg')
    rgr [options] <regex> [paths...]

OPTIONS
    ALL OPTIONS ACCEPTED BY RIPGREP ('rg') ARE ALSO ACCEPTED BY THIS PROGRAM. Here are just a few
    of the options I've amended and/or would like to highlight. Not all Ripgrep options have been
    tested, and not all of them ever will be by me at least.

    -h, -?, --help
        Print help menu
    -v, --version
        Print version information.
    --run_tests
        Run unit tests (none yet).
    -d, --debug
        Turn on debug prints. '-d' is not part of 'rg' but if you use either of these options here
        it will auto-forward '--debug' to 'rg' under-the-hood.
    -r <replacement_text>, --replace <replacement_text>
        Do a dry-run to replace all matches of regular expression 'regex' with 'replacement_text'.
        This only does the replacement in the stdout output; it does NOT modify your disk!
    -R <replacement_text>, --Replace <replacement_text>
        THIS IS THE ONE! Bingo! This is the sole purpose for the creation of this wrapper. This
        option will actually replace all matches of regular expression 'regex' with
        'replacement_text' ON YOUR DISK. It actually modifies your file system! This is great
        for large code-wide replacements when programming in large repos, for instance.
    --stats
        Show detailed statistics about the ripgrep search and replacements made.

    SEE ALSO 'rg -h' AND 'man rg' FOR THE FULL HELP MENU OF RIPGREP ITSELF, WHICH OPTIONS ARE ALSO
    ALLOWED AND PASSED THROUGH BY THIS 'rgr' WRAPPER PROGRAM.

EXAMPLE USAGES:

    rgr foo -r boo
        Do a *dry run* to replace all instances of 'foo' with 'boo' in this folder and down.
    rgr foo -R boo
        ACTUALLY REPLACE ON YOUR DISK all instances of 'foo' with 'boo' in this folder and down.
    rgr foo -R boo file1.c file2.c file3.c
        Same as above, but only in these 3 files.
    rgr foo -R boo -g '*.txt'
        Use a glob filter to replace on your disk all instances of 'foo' with 'boo' in .txt files
        ONLY, inside this folder and down. Learn more about RipGrep's glob feature here:
        https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-filtering-globs
    rgr foo -R boo --stats
        Replace on your disk all instances of 'foo' with 'boo', showing detailed statistics.


Note to self: the only free lowercase letters not yet used by 'rg' as of 3 Jan. 2021 are:
    -d, -k, -y

This program is part of eRCaGuy_dotfiles: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles
by Gabriel Staples.
```

### Ripgrep installation

For Ubuntu 20.04 or later:

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ripgrep
```

For earlier versions of Ubuntu, follow the Debian instructions here: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation