# How do I change mirrors in Ubuntu Server from regional to main?

Tags: server, command-line, software-sources, apt-mirror

I have a Lucid Server (10.04) set up and I would like to change the mirror from US (or any other country) to the Main Ubuntu Mirror.

For example my two first entries in sources.list are:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
```

In a Desktop environment I would select the main mirror like this:

[image: Software Sources]

But how do I do that from the terminal as I don't have a graphical environment installed!

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Open your `sources.list` file using your favorite text editor, e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Locate the text `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and replace it with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

Comment: I've figured this would do the trick but when I did as you suggested but it gave me a 404 error for the repository. I've checked again now and it seems to be okay. It seemed to be a problem with my network connection. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: is there a secure way like with the GUI. I mean, not replacing it manually and avoiding typos or whatever.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands @logoff

Comment: Also run `apt-get update` subsequently so that APT can update its packages.  Initially I got an `Package X has no installation candidate` message because APT hasn't yet scanned the new repository for packages.

Comment: To use it in a script the following `sed` command can be used `sed -E -i 's#http://[^\s]*archive\.ubuntu\.com/ubuntu#http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu#g' /etc/apt/sources.list'` /etc/apt/sources.list replace *nl* with your country code.

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @MandyS for me that one didn't work... I had to use `sed -E -i 's#http://[a-z]*archive\.ubuntu\.com/ubuntu#http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu#g' /etc/apt/sources.list'` (or without the `be.`-prefix/ a custom one, the problem was the prefix-regex)

Comment: Gosh thank you, finally found this. +1

Answer (score 89):

This command should do the trick:

```
sudo sed -i 's|http://us.|http://|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It will remove the 'us.' prefix in each of the addresses to convert them to addresses of the main server.

Of course replace 'us' by any other mirror you are using.

**In depth explanation of command:**

***sed*** - stream editor for filtering and transforming text.

- The ***-i*** argument is to edit a file in place.
- Then **'s|regexp|replacement|g'**, ***s*** specifying the search and
  replace command.
- The ***g*** at the end being the argument to "globally" search.
- **Conclusion:** replaces all occurrences of **http://us.** with **http://** in the file **/etc/apt/sources.list**.

Comment: Try explaining the command a little more, what does it do?

Comment: To switch from us to de mirror do the following: `sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/us./http:\/\/de./g' /etc/apt/sources.list'`

Comment: The method posted here is right, however the code posted in the top is wrong [code] "sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/us./http:\/\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list"[/code] where are the sed cmd posted at the bottom makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the manual-text-editing-free one-liner. I went from a few kB/s download speed to 10 MB/s by using `sudo sed -i 's|http://us.|http://ch.|g' /etc/apt/sources.list` (I'm in Switzerland). I was working with an osboxes image and they are apparently quite misconfigured in that regard...

Comment: ok, this works good. I tried it on my ubuntu linode server.

Answer (score 7):

Correct sed usage to remove/change country code "us" from source.list to something else like "au", the command will be as follows:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/us./http:\/\/au./g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or just to remove "us" alone instead of changing it to something, use code below:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/in./http:\/\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 4):

With `vim`:

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bak}   # you may want to make a backup
vim /etc/apt/source.list
```

Type <kbd>:</kbd> (you need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>) to enter command-ine mode, and then type:

```
%s/http:\/\/us\./http:\/\//g
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to be sure you've exited the command-line mode and entered normal mode. Now you can scroll around the file with keyboard move keys (if you want) to make sure all occurrences of *us* mirrors have been edited.

Finally, exit with saving by entering command-line mode (type <kbd>:</kbd>) and enter `wq!` to save and exit `vim`.

Comment: here in the search regexp %s/http:\/\/us\./http:\/\//g ;   "." (dot) is not a delimiter , so don't need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: @SAGARBHOOSHAN [`.` by itself is "any character except new line"](http://vimregex.com/#metacharacters). The backslash is to ensure it only matches a literal  dot.