# Sharing a folder on local network

Tags: file-sharing, shared-folders

I am new to Ubuntu and I installed the Ubuntu 11.10 on my system. I want to share a folder on my local network. How can I do that?

I want to share a folder by right click on it. when I do this then it say to install the samba and when I try to install the samba then it show some files not found on ubuntu server.
On installation process time I got the error lik

```
root@sys:~# sudo apt-get install samba

Reading package lists... 
Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... 
Done 
The following extra packages will be installed:  
libwbclient0 samba-common smbclient 
Suggested packages:  openbsd-inetd inet-superserver smbldap-tools ldb-tools cifs-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:  samba
The following packages will be upgraded: libwbclient0 samba-common smbclient
3 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 372 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 23.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
 libwbclient0 smbclient samba-common samba
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main libwbclient0 i386 2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1  404  Not Found
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main smbclient i386 2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1  Bad header line
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main samba-common all 2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1  404  Not Found
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main samba i386 2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1  404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/libwbclient0_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/smbclient_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  Bad header line
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_all.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: There are many ways of sharing folders. Can you edit your question to state exactly what you want to accomplish? Are there different systems in your network? Should they be accessible from the internet, etc.

Comment: Yes, all other system have XP on local net.They are working fine and accessible to each other.

Comment: The way you are going about it is the correct way.  You appear to be getting an error message which we need to see to help you.

Comment: Phil Hannent :@:--> you can check the errors in question now.

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/124405/sharing-a-folder-on-local-network

Answer (score 2):

Since the right click isn't working for you, open a Terminal window and enter the following command:

> sudo apt-get install samba smbfs

That should install the software you need.  Then retry the right click and share option.

Comment: I used that command which you told, It run completely fine but the problem is remain same

Comment: @GhostAnswer Its showing that it cannot find the required files on the ubuntu repository server.  You'll need to change repositories and try again:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main

Answer (score 1):

- Open software center and install `samba` from there. See the picture below.

[image: samba]

- After installation launch `samba`. You will see a window like below. Click on `+` icon to add a new share. 
  [image]
- Alternatively right click on a folder and choose `sharing options`

Comment: Please not another Samba proposal. Don't use Samba if you don't have to. There are far better options for Ubuntu users.

Comment: Web-E :@:--> I already used these steps but the installation not completed and give the error like I shown now in my question.

Comment: Anders Wallenquist:@:--> whick kind of option you are talking. please tell

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way are using UbuntuOne. Right-click and share any folder with any one in the world.

Another easy way, and very secure are using SSH and "File/Connect to server" in Nautilus your file handler. On the machine that has the folder you want to share you have to install openssh-server from Ubuntu program center (its listed as an technical object).

The latter method uses strong enchryption and you can use the same technique shareing the folder over Internet.

Comment: he is not asking sharing in Internet. He wants to share it in local intra-net.

Comment: Well, SSH is still the best way to share folders, intranet or not. I have installed this for hundreds of users, it much better than Samba, ftp or Dav for a couple of reasons. The back-side of SSH are that you have to install a package on the machine where the shared folder is.

For a beginner UbuntuOne and the concepts that comes with UbuntuOne can appear more winning. You are not confronted with user-ids, read-write modes and stuff.
It't a good thing that booth SSH and UbuntuOne works booth for intra-net and over Internet. Its a good thing you can use the same concept in several contexts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple article you can follow:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/a-quick-way-to-share-folders-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Comment: As long you want to share folders with Ubuntu-machines, its best to avoid Samba. Samba implements Windows sharing protocoll that are old and clunky. 
The only reason to use Samba are if you have old Windows boxes and users that don't want to learn something better.
Window boxes can share folders with Ubuntu users using WinScp or Expandrive. If this is possibe, its a much better solution.

Comment: aneeshep :@:--> I already used these steps but the installation not completed and give the error like I shown now in my question.