# Unable to update from 12.04 to 14.04 using update manager

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

When I type hwe-support-status --verbose I get "Forcefully disabled hwe-support-status via file /var/lib/update-notifier/disable-hwe-eol-messages.

When I try to update via Update Manager I get a message fetch failed to upgrade. There maybe a network problem.

Anybody who can help me to upgrade to latest version of Ubuntu I would be grateful.

Comment: `update-manager -d` brings up the Update Manager window which says New Ubuntu release '12.10' is available. When I click upgrade I get the same old error

Comment: Right, you need to go to 14.04 first... What about the command `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is not released yet making this question off topic.  If you want play with a release still being developed I suggest you download the iso and install it in a Virtual machine such as VirtualBox.

Comment: When I type do-release-upgrade I get this message Checking for a new Ubuntu release Err Upgrade tool signature 404 Not Found Err Upgrade tool 404 Not found. Warning: root:file 'quantal.tar.gz.gpg' missing. Failed to fetch. Fetching the upgrade failed. There maybe a network problem.

Comment: Are you really trying to upgrade to 14.10 (rather than 14.04)? If so, you'll need to upgrade to 14.04 first anyway. 12.10 is end-of-life, which is probably the reason for your message: it seems to be trying to upgrade to 12.10 instead of 14.04. You should be able to fix this by setting `Prompt=lts` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` as detailed in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/461235) to [Why is “No new release found” when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](http://askubuntu.com/q/125392).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong subject. I am trying to update to latest supported version i.e. 14.04.

Comment: I update the file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades prompt=lts and I typed do-release-upgrade and I get this message now - Checking for a new Ubuntu release. No new release found.

Comment: Apologies for the extraneous comment. So should I just wait with my 12.04 version and not upgrade till the 14.04 version is fully supported ? Because when I just to upgrade to 14.04 version It says Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics harware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade.

Comment: Hello Eliah Kagan, Making that change to the file did not help. Any further changes ? Thank you.

Comment: @WarrenHill FTR, questions about upgrading to a development release aren't off-topic. OT-dev questions are either unanswerable because things are undecided or in flux (will Ubuntu 22.10 use Mir?), or because they're straight up bugs that need reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using Xubuntu 12.04. Even trying to change the sources list, it didn't work. There are two options (one will work without any problems):

1- Download the ISO, and when installing it, there will be an option to upgrade your distro to the new version. It will keep your configurations and programs.

2- Check this option here. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499512. If it works for you, then perfect.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. While it is always good to cite ones sources, it would be greatly appreciated, if you post the relevant parts directly in your answer. This ensures, that the answer is still of use should the original page change.

Comment: Thank you. I posted the link mostly because I found it after reading the question. I haven't tested it so I haven't put more details because of that. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. My friend suggested [changing the repository to the main server rather than a mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main). I refreshed and 14.04 finally came up. I'm not sure if there are a bunch of out of date mirrors at the moment or what!