# Can't get rid of GPG error in apt

Tags: 14.04, server, apt

Before you mark this one duplicate hear me out:

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting the following classic error:

```
W: GPG error: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

So the first thing I've tried was of course

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
```

which updated the key with new signatures but didn't solve the GPG error. If I run it again the key remains unchanged.

I did some research (read about 10 questions around here, all marked duplicate) and also tried removing `/var/lib/apt/lists` (https://askubuntu.com/a/64544/43951), which also didn't do it.

If I run

```
sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update
```

I don't get the signature error but bad hashes:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages: Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages: Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages: Hash Sum mismatch
```

Comment: Did you try this solution ? http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=802453

Comment: @sparkmood Just gave it a try using the `gpg` command as he desribed in his question, didn't work.

Comment: Tried a different mirror?

Comment: @muru That did the trick. Seems `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com` was faulty. `http://archive.ubuntu.com` works :-)

Comment: This is not the first time I have seen `de` having a problem on this site. Somebody should file a bug.

Comment: @muru I'd say this deserves to be converted to a proper answer.

Comment: Come on @muru: you know the drill: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby I voted to close as localised actually. I'd bet that if op tried now, or in a couple of days, the mirror would be fine.

Comment: @muru I guess so but it could happen agein. Next time a mirror is faulty this question and answer might help someone.

Comment: In which case, I think the answer should be on the original GPG post. I'll mark to close as a dupe and flag for merging.

Comment: @muru that would be fine with me too

Comment: @Fabby bugs should be either closed as off topic (if it is a bug without a doubt), or, at best, as a dupe if it exists already on AU.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Voted accordingly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a different mirror, like to the non-regional specific `http://archive.ubuntu.com`. Doing this is covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main).

You can also find out more mirrors [on the Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors).