# How can I boost my download speed for the softwares I download from ubuntu software centre?

Tags: software-center, 14.10, download-speed

I have a lan connection with average download speed of about 5-6 MBps.
But ubuntu software centre doesn't download at that speed. I even checked my speed by downloading from other sources but they were giving a download speed in Mbps. Is there a way I can boost up speed because downloading packages as big in Giga Bytes can become cumbersome at speed of 70-100 Kbps.

Comment: What server are you using? http://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could follow [this article as to how use mirror-servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror). The python-script seems promising, but adds manual labour.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In this case, closing as a duplicate is possible better, but you make that decision :)

Comment: Ah yes, because your one-liner as a comment is so much more elaborate? Fair enough, point taken, I will better my life!

Comment: My one liner does say possible duplicate. As you have 34 reputation, you can't see it currently, but this has 2 close votes, and will be in the close queue - so other users with 3000 rep + will also vote to close. We like to close as duplicate so that there ins't knowledge floating around all over the place, it's all together.