# Failure while apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt

Just installed server 14.04 LTS on server i have, but everytime i try to use "`apt-get update`" it fails with the output:

```
....    
    Reading package lists... Error!
    E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
    E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en
    E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I also tried multiple times to that [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err):

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf && apt-get update
```

I got the same error:

```
.....
Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en [102 kB]                                                                  
Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en [3457 B]                                                                  
Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4089 kB]                                                                   
Fetched 32.7 MB in 3min 43s (146 kB/s)                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Any Ideas?

**Edit**

```
apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Solutions there didn't work with me,

Comment: What exactly is the matter with that particular file? Does it exist on your system? It ought to be fairly long, around 18Mb. If it's not there at all or has been damaged during download, perhaps you can download it manually (from [here](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en), obviously) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. [Grunnar](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson)'s idea, and also thanks to that [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/558708) to change the Ubuntu's mirrors,
I did that:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/us./http:\/\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Removing all "us." perfix in the file, and made it pointing to the mainserver itself,

And it fixed my issue,

Comment: Great! Then can you please mark your own answer as the best, to denote that the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Good luck.

Comment: didn't work, please check output of  "`apt-get install -f`", i edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I already tried those multiple times, as i mentioned in the post, but same error,

Comment: @user225844: Sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough. Another idea is to switch mirror: Open _Software & Updates_ and change "Download from" to e.g. "Main server".

Comment: My case is server not desktop, but the idea helped a lot :), i changed the sources.list file, thanks alot :)

Comment: @user225844: Sorry for reading your question so bad. :( Anyway, glad it helped. Probably it's a temporary glitch with the US mirror, and it will probably be corrected soon.