# Error In Ubuntu Server

Tags: 14.04, server, 13.04, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have a trouble when I install ubuntu server. I use wireless connection to install. I have finished installation. But, when I write `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. It showed `Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'`. I searched and solve many method, for example setting DNS. But, still not working.

Comment: If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's something wrong with the mirror server and since you don't have a gui to change the Download location, you can try this:

- `sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list`
- then find `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and replace it with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

More info here: [How do I change mirrors in Ubuntu Server from regional to main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main/104701#104701)
Tell me if that helps.