# apt-get generally fails, with software packages and with update

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

I am running a VM of Ubuntu server 14.04.4 using virtual box. I have configured the network to be in "bridged adapter" config.
I have manually assigned IP of the same address as the network the host windows machine is on. Gateway is the wireless router. I am able to ping public IPs and URIs are being translated as well.

When i try to install a software package like 'chrony', with `sudo apt-get install chrony`, i get the following output immediately.

```
root@controller:~# apt-get install chrony
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package chrony
```

When I try to update apt with `sudo apt-get update` I get the output,

```
    root@controller:~# apt-get update
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

#2nd if
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.0.1


dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
```

my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.4 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160217.1)]/ trusty main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.4 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160217.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

I have tried to disable IPv6 routing for this. I havent faces such an issue with previous attempts, I feel stumped after three days. Any insight would be appreciated. Feels like I have missed something glaringly obvious, but being oblivious to it.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I think the Download Server is borken. Try changing to `Main Server` by remove tin `in.` in every uncommented line at your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as described here http://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main. Then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Do you mean to replace `in.` with `main.` in the `sources.list` file?

Comment: For example make the line `deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse` look like `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse`.

Comment: didn't change any thing. Deleted the '  sources.list' and replaced it with another standard one. Didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping '`google.com`' ... and if it failed to ping then do the following:

Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add

**NOTICE:** You can use any text editor, for example '`vi /etc/resolv.conf`'

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

At the end of `/etc/resolv.conf` - or at the top if it was empty file.

It should work now, please tell me what happened in the comments :)

**EDIT:** I noticed in /etc/network/interfaces - that's you already have the "dns-nameservers" field initlized to the Google Nameservers, but try doing that on my method too :)

Comment: But editing '/etc/resolv.conf' by hand makes the changes non persistent. That is why added them n interfaces file. Anyh way, I am able to ping several FQDNs, so doesn't seem like a DNS issue.

Comment: Check the above answer, (tested).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Well! this solution will 100% fix it (I hope) ... Because I tried to use your '**`sources.list`**' copy and I got the same problem... After that I tried to revert the default 'sources.list' using the below method and it **100% worke**d **(Tested!)** :)

Well, as your network settings are fine and you're able to ping everything well. Let's restore the default '`sources.list`' file of your Ubuntu installation.

So start by deleting the corrupted '`sources.list`' and we will replace it in the next steps:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now open '`software-properties-gtk`' which will automatically create a new empty '`sources.list`' file

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

In '`software-properties-gtk`' , tick (check) '`Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)`'

Then set '`Download from:`' as '`Server for USA`' or any server which is near to your location.

And of course, click the '`Revert`' button.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NsN4.png)

Comment: this is does not help, need apt to install 'software-properties-gtk' , and running ubuntu server without gui.can't try this since i don't have apt working. Replacing sources.list by other means does not work either. Ty for trying.