# Connection error while upgrading 14.04LTS to16.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, do-release-upgrade

I have a connection error while upgrade ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS.

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial/universe libkf5activitiesexperimentalstats1 amd64 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

how to fix this problem? 
note: The internet connection works properly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to A.U. It would be best if you mentioned whether it is desktop or server? When I tried to ping that it times out but might just be an intermittent issue. You can try to change mirrors: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main

Comment: Hi Craig van Tonder. It is Ubuntu Desktop. I also tried to ping 91.189.88.149 several times. The server give response.