# Error while executing "sudo apt-get install -f"

Tags: apt, 17.10

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas
  address-book-service biometryd-bin evolution-data-server-utouch
  gcc-6-base:i386 history-service indicator-network indicator-transfer
  indicator-transfer-download-manager libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-facebook libaccount-plugin-flickr
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1
  libandroid-properties1 libass5 libbiometryd1 libboost-program-options1.62.0
  libboost-system1.61.0 libcephfs1 libclick-0.4-0 libconnectivity-qt1
  libdbus-cpp5 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libebur128-1 libertine-xmir-tools
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-pthreads-2.0-5 libgdict-1.0-10 libgdict-common
  libgflags2v5 libhardware2 libhistoryservice0 libhud2 libhybris
  libhybris-common1 libindicator-transfer0 libkpmcore4 libleveldb1v5
  liblightdm-qt5-3-0 liblivemedia57 libllvm4.0:i386 libmedia1
  libmediascanner-2.0-4 libmiral2 libmircookie2 libmirplatform15
  libmirplatform16 libmirserver43 libmirserver45 libmission-control-plugins0
  libonline-accounts-client1 libonline-accounts-daemon1 libonline-accounts-qt1
  libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-features2d2.4v5
  libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5
  libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5 liboxideqt-qmlplugin
  liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libpcre16-3 libpkcs11-helper1
  libpoppler-qt5-1 libqdjango-db0 libqgsttools-p1 libqmenumodel0
  libqofono-qt5-0 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5contacts5 libqt5feedback5
  libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5organizer5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5quicktest5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5test5 libqt5versit5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1
  libsignon-qt5-1 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox2 libsystemsettings1
  libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtelepathy-qt5-0 libthumbnailer-qt1.0 libtrust-store2
  libubuntu-application-api3 libubuntu-location-service3
  libubuntu-platform-hardware-api3 libubuntumetrics5 libudm-priv-common1
  libunity-action-qt1 liburcu4 libusermetricsinput1 libusermetricsoutput1
  libx265-110 linux-headers-4.10.0-33 linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic
  linux-headers-4.10.0-35 linux-headers-4.10.0-35-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic
  mediascanner2.0 mir-client-platform-mesa5 mir-graphics-drivers-desktop
  mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms12 mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms13
  mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x12 mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x13
  mir-platform-input-evdev6 mir-platform-input-evdev7 network-manager-openvpn
  openvpn oxideqt-codecs-extra plainbox-provider-checkbox
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic plainbox-secure-policy policykit-unity8
  prosper python3-checkbox-support python3-guacamole python3-jinja2
  python3-padme python3-plainbox python3-pyparsing python3-xlsxwriter
  qmenumodel-qml qml-module-biometryd qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside
  qml-module-ofono qml-module-pamauthentication0.1 qml-module-qmltermwidget1.0
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
  qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtmultimedia
  qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtqml-statemachine
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qtsysteminfo
  qml-module-qttest qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2 qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics
  qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qmlscene qtcontact5-galera
  qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-dev-tools
  qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-download-manager0.1
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony0.1 qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qtubuntu-desktop repowerd
  repowerd-data signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui
  signon-ui-service signon-ui-x11 signond sox sqlite3 suru-icon-theme
  telepathy-mission-control-5 telephony-service texlive-generic-recommended
  thumbnailer-service tone-generator ubuntu-application-api3-desktop
  ubuntu-application-api3-test ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-mobile-icons
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme unity-control-center-signon unity-plugin-scopes
  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-mediascanner2 unity-system-compositor
  usermetricsservice xmir
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git libllvm5.0:i386
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
  gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libllvm5.0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  git
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 18.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 63.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 libllvm5.0 i386 1:5.0-3 [15.3 MB]
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 libllvm5.0 i386 1:5.0-3
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:f4b869ebbe1d559957313adcf42b9cbc983489bae990f3e0f0d4f43b483bcea5
   - SHA1:a4b4772a0a86306dc4d53b7d0d7b67d9f2ba2a53 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e971ee9a780018804ab04ba5f763c0b5 [weak]
   - Filesize:15319790 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:c3df345c2f7f419e0a7d2b714f79b6f61e4815f850027f7d78fe706bb53483a1
   - SHA1:3c3e682738b971fdcd8766af85172ef22b4efafb [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4deb80529ff8746f0b035a5544739038 [weak]
   - Filesize:15319790 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 01:35:00 +0000
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.14.1-1ubuntu4 [3,130 kB]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.14.1-1ubuntu4
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:9b3e2844938e4e6fae75d46713b77f0aad3de65904bae6830eb937918cd281f0
   - SHA1:4cfc1f44644fc5303751abec3a950176c8d8af03 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2144492819f6ea3bb86154fd7c6f6091 [weak]
   - Filesize:3130258 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:4a1ea5919d070cc4442b938bbd41a7a0261c77c2e5c0157bf84a75921ed75599
   - SHA1:912f4e326b6aef15c637044a83c7fa998e22ec71 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2032fe78eea746ef328eb914b2d673ad [weak]
   - Filesize:3130258 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 17:58:34 +0000
Fetched 18.5 MB in 1min 17s (238 kB/s)                                         
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-5.0/libllvm5.0_5.0-3_i386.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:f4b869ebbe1d559957313adcf42b9cbc983489bae990f3e0f0d4f43b483bcea5
    - SHA1:a4b4772a0a86306dc4d53b7d0d7b67d9f2ba2a53 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e971ee9a780018804ab04ba5f763c0b5 [weak]
    - Filesize:15319790 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:c3df345c2f7f419e0a7d2b714f79b6f61e4815f850027f7d78fe706bb53483a1
    - SHA1:3c3e682738b971fdcd8766af85172ef22b4efafb [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4deb80529ff8746f0b035a5544739038 [weak]
    - Filesize:15319790 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 01:35:00 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_2.14.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:9b3e2844938e4e6fae75d46713b77f0aad3de65904bae6830eb937918cd281f0
    - SHA1:4cfc1f44644fc5303751abec3a950176c8d8af03 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2144492819f6ea3bb86154fd7c6f6091 [weak]
    - Filesize:3130258 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:4a1ea5919d070cc4442b938bbd41a7a0261c77c2e5c0157bf84a75921ed75599
    - SHA1:912f4e326b6aef15c637044a83c7fa998e22ec71 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2032fe78eea746ef328eb914b2d673ad [weak]
    - Filesize:3130258 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 17:58:34 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: You can not fix a hash sum mismatch on your end. You can try an alternate mirror or file a bug report . You may wish to run `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Please tell me how to do that

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt - https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#Secure_apt_groundwork:_checksums . The package maintainer / reposiroty maintainer has to update the checksums, you can not. To change mirrors see https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main