# Hash Sum mismatch error when trying to upgrade

Tags: apt, hash

I am getting this error when trying to upgrade:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157.15_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
```

To check what is wrong I downloaded the package from [the address](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/all/linux-firmware/download) and checked the md5 which is showing something different in my machine from the one given on the website.

Answer (score 2):

That generally means that the download was corrupted. Try the following to remove the downloaded file and retry the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: tried :/ still same

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server that might cache the downloads?

Comment: nope, i am wondering why is that md5 sum is given on https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/all/linux-firmware/download ,if u try to manually download and check both are different

Comment: here in my machine its 2a7001cd87df0e459eb7fe5b98c8f77e and on website its c144ae5a59948a989a4695de73f11eac

Comment: can you try with
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: then try `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the previous answer:

Delete your local copy of the file. Choose a [different apt mirror](https://askubuntu.com/q/104695/805086) (to prevent caching of the corrupt download by some transparent proxy) and retry.