# Install libinput-tools on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, touchpad, libinput

I am trying to setup multitouch gestures on ubuntu 17.10, but for some reason, I can't install libinput-tools.

Error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libinput-tools : Depends: libinput10 (= 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) but 1.8.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I know libnput10 is installed by default because ubuntu 17.10 replaced synaptics, so libinput-tools should work too?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working on outdated repository packages for some reason (I've installed it locally, all the correct versioned dependencies are available).

There are a number of reasons* why this may be the case, but try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

* Reasons for outdated repository packages/info:

1. You haven't pulled the latest package list (see `sudo apt-get
   update` to do this)
2. The repository mirror is out of date - ie it
   should have sync'd from the main ubuntu repositories, but for
   whatever reason, that sync didn't happen/happened halfway through an
   update/failed to complete for some reason.

   This issue is out of your control (you can't fix the repository), but you can change which mirror your install points to - check out this thread:

   [How do I change mirrors in Ubuntu Server from regional to main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main)

   Then retry the two original steps above -