# Unmet dependencies: shim-signed

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, uefi

So it started here:

```
wine *.exe
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
```

I try then:

```
sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have recently upgraded system twice: from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and from 20.04 to 22.04(.1)
Popular solution to purge grub doesn't work - it gives the same "shim-signed" error.
Also update, upgrade, autoremove, install -f gives nothing.
Grub repair and re-installation also doesn't solve.

Oh, and  I'm not using (U)EFI boot, just legacy BIOS, no efi partition at all.
What can I possibly try before complete OS re-installation - to get wine working again?

Comment: If you really have bios then try to remove the package.

Comment: I think i have this problem too, I need a clean apt upgrade before I can upgrade to 22.04, I think I am using UEFI, I get something about that in grub menu, anyidea how I find out if I am or get rid of the dep before upgrade?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082929/shim-signed-depends-shim-151533136590-3beb971-0ubuntu1-but-13-0ubuntu2-i
seems that these two packages must be released together and before they were not. could that have happened again?

Comment: Note to future-self, if you try to apt remove these you get scary warnings but you can ignore them and apt remove both shim and shim-signed if you dont use UEFI boots