# Installing Snaps in China is too slow

Tags: snap, download-speed

When I try to install anything using snap, I found out that the download speed is very slow. As shown in the screenshot, it is about 20 kb/s:

[image]

How can I install a snap fast?

Comment: May be your internet speed is slow by default? If not, try to change The update servers by following this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main)

Comment: We wont be able to answer this. The speed is mostly determined by external factors like your internet connection and the server providing your software. Plus traffic is regulated in China.

Comment: There's a CDN used for delivering snaps from the store. Perhaps there's an issue between you and the fastly cdn. They have a debug page at http://www.fastly-debug.com/ which can be used to determine speed of connection to the CDN. Note it's JS based, so you'll need to disable ad-blockers to use it.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a same problem. Snap uses Fastly CDN, which means your speed is determined by which Fastly CDN node you get. If you get a nearest one, the speed can be very quick.

You can execute this command to find out which node you got: `dig fastly.cdn.snapcraft.io` For me, it was **151.101.26.217** and very slow.

So I changed it to **151.101.62.217** in `/etc/hosts` and the speed improved from 10k/s to 1M/s. I installed pycharm in 5 minutes.

How to set hosts? Just add a new line in your `/etc/hosts`:

```
151.101.62.217  fastly.cdn.snapcraft.io
```

Comment: I've noticed that this approach no longer works for somebody. That's because Snap doesn't always use Fastly CDN now. They are using canonical CDN `canonical-bos01.cdn.snapcraft.io`.

Comment: Because `canonical-bos01.cdn.snapcraft.io` has only 2 valid IP addresses(both of them are very slow in China), So we cannot change to a faster IP address.
This approach is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following config to your `/etc/hosts`:

```
91.189.91.43    darkbowser.canonical.com
```

Then you will get a very fast speed.

[image: snapspeed]

Comment: Interesting.  Could you explain where you got those values?  They differ from other answers and could change in the future.

Comment: This one works for me as well. However, I'd like to know why this works.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in China. Download speed increased from 20kB to 900kB/s.

```
sudo snap install snap-store-proxy
sudo snap install snap-store-proxy-client
```

I tried [the answer by Genghis Yang](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169928/816190) but no improvement for me.

Comment: Works for me XD

Answer (score 1):

Use dns checker service on the web to get the nearest ip of fastly.cdn.snapcraft.io, in my case it went up from 25KB/s to 25MB/s

`84.200.69.80 (DNS.WATCH - DE)`

[image]