# Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, updates, update-manager

> lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I tried finding error what to remove and what not but couldn't figure out. Can any other help me with which ppa is causing this problem?

```
> sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease      
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Hit:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image]

Comment: I received similar error when I was connected to VPN, after disconnecting from VPN error got resolved

Answer (score 1):

changing servers from **India** to **Main** fixed the problem: [How do I change mirrors in Ubuntu Server from regional to main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main)