# Cant install steam because of 32 bit libraries "missing"

Tags: steam, libraries

i just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and installed steam launcher.When i run it, this pops up.

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for pukar: 
..........W: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to np.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (120.89.98.2), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to np.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to np.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libcrypt1

Package libgl1:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
Press return to continue:
```

i am really new to Linux and know only the very basics. i figured out installing those libraries would solve it, but i haven't found  any ways to do so.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you have no connection to `np.archive.ubuntu.com`. I can confirm that this server does not respond at this moment. Simply try again later.

Comment: okay, ill try it later. thank you so much.

Comment: Consider switching country mirrors in the interim, or using another mirror like the core archive mirrors at `archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get cannot connect to Ubuntu archives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198621/apt-get-cannot-connect-to-ubuntu-archives)

Comment: changing the link worked. thank you all so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a 'missing libraries' problem, this is a "Dead Repository Mirror" issue - namely, `np.archive.ubuntu.com` points to a dead mirror server right now.  As such, your system isn't able to get an updated package list to determine if the packages you need are actually available.

**Temporary Workaround**:

Go into your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as an administrator (such as with `pkexec gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` or `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` for command line editors on the Terminal), and replace all references of `np.archive.ubuntu.com` with `archive.ubuntu.com` which points to the primary Archive mirrors at Canonical/Ubuntu.

Then run your `sudo apt update` and then attempt to install Steam again.  It should then work, though it won't be a more 'regional' mirror so your downloads might be slower to an extent.

---

**Fixes on np.archive.ubuntu.com are completed, thanks to the Mirrors Team!**

The mirror in question was redirected to the primary archive mirrors for now because the only mirror that the regional mirror pointed at is dead.  This should have taken effect within the past 25 or so minutes as of the edit done to this post at ~13:45 UTC.  So barring any stale DNS resolution records in your system, `np.archive.ubuntu.com` should now point at working mirrors.

(Historical information remains below.)

Per https://rt.ubuntu.com/Ticket/Display.html?id=35715 on the Ubuntu RT ticketing system (thank you to the Mirrors Team for referring me to this), the np.archive.ubuntu.com mirror (which is run from ubuntu.ntc.net.np actually) has been down for more than a day.

I prodded the Mirrors people today, and they are going to repoint the DNS for this to the archive mirrors in Ubuntu namespace at some point during the day, no ETA as of yet.

Comment: yep this worked. thank you sooo much.

Comment: samething happens with `il.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: @Chiptus email mirrors@ubuntu.com and put in a ticket about it being broken.  This isn't the place to report mirrors being busted.  Also, can't reproduce here.