# apt-get update not working, Unable to connect archive.ubuntu

Tags: apt, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I was facing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401083/unable-to-install-network-manager) issue, and while trying to fix that I am facing new error now. For command

> sudo apt-get update

I am getting

```
 Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.39). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

and

```
Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com
```

If I try to access https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu from my browser it shows "This site can’t be reached".

I have tried all the solutions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198621/apt-get-cannot-connect-to-ubuntu-archives).

Comment: Hello. Sounds like your DNS is not working. Can you access other sites in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can access other sites.

Comment: Could be temp failure try again later.

Comment: So you fixed that other problem and you got network-manager up and running?

Comment: Yup. I was able to install network manager through snap store but still can't connect to the wifi and unable to run sudo apt-get update

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401357/unable-to-connect-to-wifi-after-installing-snap-network-manager?noredirect=1#comment2431671_1401357

Comment: archive.ubuntu.com is not an https (port 443) site. It's an http (port 80) site. Connection attempts using https will fail.