# Unable to install Git. "Connection timed out" and "could not connect" error showing

Tags: server, internet, connection

I am new to programming, currently trying to install git but unable to do so...it showing following output on terminal.

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-5520:~$ sudo apt install git
[sudo] password for dell: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.5 kB/7,727 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1                                                               
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1
  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Can you share which server is configured in 'Software & Updates', under download from ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get cannot connect to Ubuntu archives](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198631/167115)

Comment: Yeah as @mchid suggested, changing the server to main/other region might help, If there is some temporary issue with the current regional server you use.

Comment: As of today(29-May-2022 IST noon), nearly for last ~24 hrs the Indian server is not responding but UK does.

Comment: It is showing "Server for India" in "Software & Updates"

Comment: @PradeepYDK Change to the main server or you could possibly choose the option to "select the fastest server".

Comment: The main server is `archive.ubuntu.com` instead of `in.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Hi everyone, looks like changing the Server to "main server" worked. Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Is it good if I choose the option "Select Best Server" under Software&Updates, allowing ubuntu to automatically connect with the whichever best server available

Comment: If i remembered correctly, 'select best server' triggers a one time test, to choose, then use the selected server in following update events and there is no harm is going with this approach