# Help stuck and don't know which way to go

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, software-center

```
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InReleas
    Temporary faliure resolving 'us.archivve.ubuntu.com'
Err: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease 
    Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://secruity.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
    Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err: 6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
Reading packages lists... Done 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease Temporary 
   failure resolving 'us.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/  
   InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archiveubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/ 
   InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com"
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease 
   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal- 
   security/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones 
   used instead.
```

Comment: Check your internet connection and/or try again later.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the guidelines to see how to properly pose a question so you can get a good answer. 
From the output it looks like you run apt update and the repositories you are using are not resolvable by your current network configuration.
It may be because you have no internet connection (wired, wifi) or the router you are connected to does not. 
Another cause can be your DNS configuration.

It looks like at least us.ubuntu.com is not an existing repository or at least not currently available. Try to change your repositories.

Here are some pointers for that :
[How do I change mirrors in Ubuntu Server from regional to main?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main)

If that doesn solve the issue, please post what you are trying, if you can go to say google.com in browser and what results you get with a working mirror.

Good luck!