# Add/edit line text in file without open editor (linux command)

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I know how to add new text to a file, but how can I edit it?

Example: adding `hello_world = 1` to test.txt using the following command:

```
echo "hello_world = 1" >> test.txt
```

But how can I change `1` to `0` or something else?

Comment: What is your mean by without open editor i.e. you don't want use also **useful CLI text editor like: `vi` or `nano`** as well as GUI like: `gedit`

Comment: because I want to make a script for my android, I know android use linux kernel and has some linux command. And my script working perfectly

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/1/0/g' test.txt
```

In general:

```
sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' filename
```

See `man sed` for more info.

Comment: for single substitution, you don't even need a global flag.

Comment: Downvote because answer is already exists [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands).

Comment: Why do you downvote the correct answer then, cOrp, and not the duplicate question?

Answer (score 5):

Through awk,

```
awk '{sub(/1/,"0")}1' infile > outfile
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'hello_world = 1' | awk '{sub(/1/,"0")}1'
hello_world = 0
```