# using sed replace the new line with character

Tags: scripts, sed, text-processing

I am using `sed` to remove the new line and replace with `<br>` but I am not able to get the desired output.

I wrote:

```
find . -name $1 -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's|\n|ABC|g'
```

...but this doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find and replace text within a file using commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)

Comment: You can invoke programs on `find` results a bit more elegantly with the `-exec` action: `find . -name $1 -exec sed -i '' -e 's|\n|ABC|g' \{\} +`

Comment: @Pandya I don't believe this is a duplicate, the OP is already using what that question would suggest, he just needs help getting the exact command for his specific environment correct, which that question won't provide.

Comment: You can use `tr '\n' '<br>' < file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed expression is treating each line separately - so it doesn't actually read the newline character into the pattern buffer and hence can't replace it. If you just want to add `<br>` while retaining the actual newline as well, you can just use the end-of-line marker `$` and do

```
sed -i'' 's|$|<br>|' file
```

Note that the empty backup file name - if you use it - must directly follow the `-i` like `-i''`; also the `-e` is not necessary when using a single expression.

OTOH if you really want to replace actual newline characters, you need to jump through some extra hoops, for example

```
sed -i'' -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/<br>/;ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

or, more compactly

```
sed -i'' ':a; $!N; s|\n|<br>|; ta; P;D' file
```

which read successive *pairs* of lines into the pattern buffer and then replace the intervening newline - see [Famous Sed One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  replace the new line and with `<br>`, you can use

```
 find . -name $1 -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/.*$/&<br\>/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

`find . -name $1 | xargs sed -ri "s/$/<br>/"`

?

(Try without the `i`, first ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

To replace inline `\n` with `<br>`, just use perl (or sed), needless to call `find` for that task:

```
perl -pi -e "s/$/<br>/" myfile
```

Or for an alias:

```
alias brtag='perl -pi -e "s/$/<br>/" $1'
```