# Replacing a string by a file using Sed

Tags: sed

Lets say i have two files **foo** and **bar**. I want a replace the string "*this is test*" in **foo** with the contents of the file **bar**. How can i do this using a one liner **sed**?

I have used:

```
sed -i.bak 's/this is test/$(cat bar)\n/g' foo
```

but the the string is being replaced by literal `$(cat bar)` rather than the contents of `bar`. I have tried using quotations but the result remains the same.

Radu's answer is correct as far as the quote is concerned. Now the problem is lets say my bar file contains:

```
this
is
a
test
file
```

Now if i run the command it gives an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command

18 times.

Comment: does the contents of the file bar contains newline characters?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: please check my edits.

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? To avoid escaping issues, I'd rather use another scripting language that is better suited for file interaction like Awk, Python, Perl, Ruby, or whatnot.

Comment: I was trying to check this using sed. So it would be great if a solution is available in Sed.

Comment: If [you mean](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540532/replacing-a-string-by-a-file-using-sed#comment739908_540538) "this is test" is a separate line then solution is using `sed $'/this is test/ {r bar\n d}' foo` .otherwise if "this is test" is a string in a line then solution is using `X=$(echo $(cat bar));sed "s/this is test/$X/" foo`.

Comment: Got it. Now what if i want the start of the file **foo** i.e. **^** is to be replaced by the file **bar**?

Comment: escape it with "\" like `sed $'/\^/ {r bar\n d}' foo`

Comment: Actually i got my answer but this is just an extension to check if any tweaking can be done further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following command should work for what you want:

```
sed "s/this is test/$(cat bar)/" foo
```

If `foo` contain more then one line, then you can use:

```
sed "s/this is test/$(sed -e 's/[\&/]/\\&/g' -e 's/$/\\n/' bar | tr -d '\n')/" foo
```

or:

```
sed -e '/this is a test/{r bar' -e 'd}' foo
```

Source of the last two commands: [Substitute pattern within a file with the content of other file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49438/37944)

To make the change in `foo` file, use `sed -i`.

Comment: it's not working for me..

Comment: @Radu: Please check my edits. I have tried this already.

Comment: @heemayl you used the wrong quotes.

Comment: @heemayl No, you tried using simple quotes, in my answer I used double quotes. See [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash). ***Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will (for example variables, backticks, certain \ escapes, etc...)***

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: Yes, I got it. please check my edits for problem regarding new lines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj There is a solution for this also...

Comment: @heemayl Check my new edits

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct since the OP's question said replace the **string** "this is test" and not replace the line "this is test". If the line is "this is test in foo file" in foo file, then you deleted "in foo file" string at the end of that line(in your second command). but he/she marked as answer then I think the "this is test" is in a separate line not string into line but again title says that is STRING.

Comment: @KasiyA: I meant line in this case but what if i want to replace the start of first line of foo with content of file bar?

Answer (score 7):

One way:

```
sed -e '/this is test/r bar' -e '/this is test/d' foo
```

Sample result:

```
$ cat bar
12
23
$ cat foo
ab
this is test
cd
this is test
ef
$  sed -e '/this is test/r bar' -e '/this is test/d' foo
ab
12
23
cd
12
23
ef
```

Comment: Not working in my case.

Comment: "Not working" means error or result not as expected or something else?

Comment: Same mentioned error i.e. **sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command**

Comment: Can you tell me please what **/r** is doing here?

Comment: @heemayl `r` - append file to stdout after flush. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/37944

Comment: @heemayl please check that you have typed @Guru's answer exactly as shown - it does not use an `s` command

Comment: It was my mistake. +1. If i want to replace the start of first line of foo with bar what will be the modification?

Comment: And also you have [this problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540532/replacing-a-string-by-a-file-using-sed#comment739901_540538) too.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to replace an entire line with the contents of a file, you can use `r` to insert a file and `d` to delete the current line:

```
sed -e "/regex/{r/path/to/file" -e "d}"
```