# How do you create a Bash Script for replacing text in a document, utilizing regular expressions?

Tags: bash, scripts, text

Identical to this question:

[Find and replace text within a file using commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)

However I want an answer that utilizes regular expressions specifically. So in short:

Using commandline; what command can I used to search and replace text in a commandline while utilizing regular expressions?

For example:

```
search file.txt "([a-z]+)" "\1 blah"
```

Comment: post the contents of file.txt along with expected output.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sed.1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ cat file
foo bar
$ sed 's/\([a-z]\+\)/\1 blah/g' file
foo blah bar blah
```

`\([a-z]\+\)` captures one or more lowercase letters. Then the matched characters are replaced by the characters which are present inside the group index 1 plus the string " blah".

Comment: And this is case sensitive?

Comment: to do a case insensitive match `sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/\1 blah/g' file` or `sed 's/\([a-z]\+\)/\1 blah/gi' file`