# Why can't I replace a specific string with sed?

Tags: sed

I want to replace the specific string `memory_limit = 128M` with `memory_limit = 512M` in the file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
sed 's/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 512M/g'  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Why doesn't the command work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace text within a file using commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)

Comment: The command works to me. What error are you getting? Note this is going to show the replacement in the screen; if you want to replace in place, say `sed -i.bak ...` so that the original will be replaced and you will also have a safety copy with a .bak extension

Comment: The right format is :

Comment: sed -i 's/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 512M/g'  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `sed -i` to change the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '/memory_limit = /s/128/512/|x' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

1. `/memory_limit = /` find correct line
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close