# Sed command in Ubuntu not working

Tags: sed

Whenever i am using my `sed` command in ubuntu the output is not reflected in the file.

```
sed 's/dog/cat/' me
```

does not change `dog hates rat` in the file  to `cat hates rat` in the file `me`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I replace a specific string with sed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/683351/why-cant-i-replace-a-specific-string-with-sed)

Answer (score 3):

By default, `sed` does not edit the input file, it just shows the output on STDOUT.

To edit a file in place, you need the `-i` option of `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/dog/cat/' file.txt
```

After the operation, the original file will be backup up as `file.txt.bak` and the modified file will be `file.txt`.

In your case:

```
sed -i.bak 's/dog/cat/' me
```

If you do not want to keep a back up:

```
sed -i 's/dog/cat/' file.txt
```

---

From `man sed`:

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)