# Append the output of sed to a file

Tags: command-line, sed

I have two scripted files, say `file1` and `file2`. I want to take the content of `file1`, change character `a` to `A` in `file1` and append the output to `file2` without modifying the content of `file1`. I'm trying with:

```
sed -i ‘s/a/A/g’ file1 >> file2
```

but this just changes the `a` to `A` in `file1`.

Comment: the opposite of this: [Sed command in Ubuntu not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765019/sed-command-in-ubuntu-not-working)

Comment: ... fyi sed has a `y` command that is more idiomatic for single character replacements: `sed 'y/a/A/' file1 >> file2`

Comment: @steeldriver Does using `y` pose an advantage to using the `s` command?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I don't know tbh - in theory it could be more efficient since it doesn't need to invoke a regular expression engine, but whether it's actually implemented more efficiently is a different matter. Probably the OP should be using `tr` rather than `sed` in this application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `-i` flag:

```
sed 's/a/A/g' file1 >> file2
```

The `-i` flag is used to edit the specified file in place, so it does just that to `file1`. From [`man sed`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/sed.1.html):

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

       edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

The reason you get nothing appended to `file2` when you use `-i` is that `>>` is used to append `stdout` to the specified file. But since `file1` is edited in place due to `-i`, no output is generated, so nothing is appended to `file2`.