# use for loop variable inside a sed command

Tags: command-line, sed

I have based my script on the following quesstion
[Find and replace text within a file using commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)

I have a lot of files named test_xxx_01.sql in which i need to replace a text testoriginal with testoriginal_xxx
so I wrote the following command

```
for i in {220,630,1000}; do sed -i 's/testoriginal/testoriginal_\$\{i\}/g' test_${i}_01.sql; done
```

the expected output is that in the file test_221_01.sql, i should now have 'testoriginal_221'.

but instead i have testoriginal_${i}

how can i fix this command?

Comment: It's basically a matter of using the right quotes - but be careful of metacharacters. See [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution)

Comment: You need to use double quotes for the expression.